# How to query all lists that use a certain content type in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

I have the following CAML query:

```
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='PublishToSM' />
            <Value Type='Boolean'>True</Value>
         </Eq>
         <IsNull>
            <FieldRef Name='SMUpdateDate' />
         </IsNull>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

I have only one content type that uses these fields.  When I run this query against a list that uses this content type everything works fine.  When I run it against a List that does not it throws the error:  `One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.`

I would like to be able to search all Lists on all websites in a site collection.  Can this be done without erroring out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SPSiteDataQuery, add a where clause to include the content type. i.e.:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
      <Value Type='Text'>CONTENTTYPE NAME</Value>
    </Eq>
    <And>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='PublishToSM' />
         <Value Type='Boolean'>True</Value>
      </Eq>
      <IsNull>
        <FieldRef Name='SMUpdateDate' />
      </IsNull>
    </And>
  </And>
</Where> 

<BeginsWith>
  <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />
  <Value Type='ContentTypeId'>CONTENTTYPE ID</Value>
</BeginsWith>
```

Set the `SPSiteDataQuery`'s `Scope` property to SiteCollection. By setting the `Lists` property you can also limit the search to for instance document libraries etc. The `ViewFields` property can be set to limit the fields retrieved (i.e. instead of the equivalent of a `select *` on the items's fields)

Comment: Hmm, this seems like it would work, but with my method before I was using `ListItem.Update` to update a field after I found it.  Would I be able to do that if i switch to `SPSiteDataQuery`?

Comment: Also, i noticed that it takes a REALLY long time to run.  Is that normal?

Comment: It ran for about 40 minutes and then gave me a "server out of memory" error when i Tired it with SPSiteDataQuery

Comment: Not it should not take long, to update the field it needs to be included in the query's ViewFields

Comment: YOu could also try and change the ContentType clause to what i put in the edit

Comment: Any idea why it would take so long?  Suggestions on where I shoudl start looking?